# How is stress marked in IPA?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, stress

I would just like to know if this is correct.

I have this text, I'm having a hard time trying to figure out this; mark primary stress (and secondary, if appropriate) on the correct syllables using IPA stress markings,and off-glides, also mark syllabic consonants.

> I will teach you in my verse
>   ˈˈaɪ wəl tˈiːtʃ jˈuː ɪn mˈaɪ versevˈɜrs
>
> Sounds like corpse, corps, horse, and worse.
>   sˈæʊndz lˈaɪk kˈɔrps kˈɔr hˈɔrs ənd wˈɜrs.
>
> I will keep you, Suzy, busy,
>   ˈaɪwəl kˈiːp jˈuː sˈuːziː bˈɪziː
>
> Make your head with heat grow dizzy.
>   mˈeɪk jˈɔr hˈed wɪð hˈiːt grˈoʊ dˈɪziː.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a homework question.

Comment: Do you have a recording to go with this? Your transcriptions are off, unless you're instructor speaks a different dialect from mine, which is possible.

Comment: Thank you guys, I think suzy, busy and dizzy are the ones with primary stress.  I'm form mexico and it is so hard to figure out this.

Comment: Are you asking which words have primary stress? All words do, it's just that monosyllables don't contrast the location, as polysyllables might.

Comment: Oh, I see, I was pretty confused about that.  Thanks 6726!

Comment: @Closevoters I would be okay with leaving this question open as long as it just asks for feedback on whether it's okay like this/possibly further hints (which it does) and not wants us to do the whole homework for him/her.

Comment: Thanks guys, no, I don't want you to do my whole homework, just need some help.  I'm still learning English(I'm from Mexico) and I need to do this IPA translation alone, ''it is almost impossible'' I'm having a hard time finding what vowels need an off-glide, stress marking, and aspiration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the accent mark goes before the first consonant of a syllable, not before the vowel. For thee most part this looks right, except I (as an native GenAmE speaker) would give an accent on 'will' also (separate from 'I')